# I need to find a part for my PCB

Tags: fan, dual

I have a PCB that I only have one component left to fit on the board, but I do not know what it is or how to get that. It say 3/8 on the part but haven't found anything like that.

The plan is [from here.](https://github.com/magkopian/prusa-mk3-24v-dual-fan-adapter/tree/master)

[image]

Comment: look at the parts list

Comment: `Is there any of you that can guide me?` has a `yes` answer, and it is not a question about electronics ... please ask about the part instead

Answer (score 2):

From the  mk3_fan_adapter.csv file, F1.

[image]

CB61F is a 2510 size fuse from Bussmann

From the schematic .sch file

[image]

Bussmann does not offer a 250mA fuse (in fact, nothing under 2A) in that series, but you can get a 3/8 (0.375)A fuse from Littelfuse [0452.375MRSN](https://www.digikey.ca/en/htmldatasheets/production/1417088/0/0/1/0452001-mrutm_adgroup=&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=PMax%20Supplier_Focus%20Supplier&utm_term=&productid=14654653&gclid=CjwKCAjwmbqoBhAgEiwACIjzEPS0wHxvo9fXYqfOuSw3EZ01t73SH6FOjhxw22WDbsx3ldaRel3fpRoChUoQAvD_BwE) which is approximately the same size (of course it's 50% higher current rating, but still adequate for protection purposes most likely, and the smallest rating LF offers in that series).

Do **check the PCB footprint dimensions** to verify the dimensions I have assumed from the .csv file are correct before you take action.

Comment: W.,r.t. _Bussmann does not offer a 250mA fuse (in fact, nothing under 2A)_ I found [Bussmann / Eaton TR2/1025TD250-R](https://www.mouser.co.uk/ProductDetail/Bussmann-Eaton/TR2-1025TD250-R?qs=KOeOmFnJLTomTHLCKCdQ%252BQ%3D%3D) which has the manufacturer "Bussmann / Eaton" and description "Surface Mount Fuses 250VAC 125VDC .25A Time Delay Brick". I think the mk3_fan_adapter.csv maybe wrong is specifying _CB61F_ since that range as you say has nothing under 2A.

Comment: @ChesterGillon Edited to make clear that I'm referring to that particular series. The TR2/1025TD250-R is similar height/width but [>10mm long](https://i.imgur.com/sAknbGw.png) rather than ~6.2mm so it certainly won't fit the PCB neatly.

Comment: The fuse in the picture appears to be a 3/8 A one, too, going by the marking.

Comment: Thank you all for giving me all this formation. So I can hp forward. Now I understand more aboute this component and i guess it not life or death if mAh not exactly is 100% correct. It's hard to find supplier with good price her in Sweden .

Comment: @mullcom Good to hear. Remember mA (current) is not the same as mAh (current * time)

Comment: After 2days of searching to get a price that I was okej with to pay. I found this site. https://reichelt.com

Answer (score 0):

Derived from https://github.com/magkopian/prusa-mk3-24v-dual-fan-adapter/blob/master/mk3_fan_adapter.xml
it looks like
Fuse_Holders_and_Fuses:Fuse_CB61F
https://www.eaton.com/us/en-us/catalog/electronic-components/cb61f-fuse.html
Maybe 3/8 А?